# method scanner input java?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to make a method that will ask the user the amount, then it checks if the amount if >0 and if it is the loop ends and if the input isnt >0 then the loop continues until proper data is entered. I can't figure out my problem..

```
/** Get principal amount **/
public static double getPrincipalAmount(double numb1) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount: ");
        double numb1 = input.nextDouble();
        double getPrincipalAmount = 0;
        if (numb1 > 0) {
            getPrincipalAmount = numb1;
        } else {    
            System.out.println("Data Error: Loan amount must be greater than zero. You entered " + numb1);
        }       
    } while (numb1 < 0);
    return getPrincipalAmount;
}
```

Comment: Well, What is the problem?

Comment: Above code won't even compile, eg. numb1 is defined twice.

Comment: Please remove compilation errors, run the code and then post the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try this!!!

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class PrinipalDemo{



    public static void main(String args[]){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double numb11;
            double getPrincipalAmount ;
           do{System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount: ");
             numb11 = input.nextDouble();
             getPrincipalAmount = 0.0;
             if(numb11 > 0)
            getPrincipalAmount = numb11;
                  else{   
                          System.out.println("Data Error: Loan amount must be greater than zero. You entered " +numb11);
                  }       
                 }while (numb11 < 0);

        System.out.println(getPrincipalAmount);

    }

}
```

Comment: added an = in your while loop. should be <= 0 :)

Comment: @Vulcan i'm talking about the while loop. not the if statement. look at my comment. its supposed to loop until a number > 0 is entered. hence it loops while number is < or = 0.

Answer (score 0):

there are several problems with your code. 
first you're passing a variable `numb1` into the method as a parameter `getPrincipalAmount(double numb1)`. thats why the new declaration is giving your a `Duplicate local variable numb1` variable.

Secondly, you're returning `getPrincipalAmount`, but it is only initialized inside the `do - while` loop. you need to initialize it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better do like this

```
public static double getPrincipalAmount(double numb1) {
    numb1 = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {

        System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount: ");
        numb1 = input.nextDouble();
        double getPrincipalAmount = 0;
        if (numb1 > 0) {
            getPrincipalAmount = numb1;
        } else {    
            System.out.println("Data Error: Loan amount must be greater than zero. You entered " + numb1);
        }       
    } while (numb1 < 0);
    return getPrincipalAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should fix such small issues, still here you go-

```
public static double getPrincipalAmount() {
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double getPrincipalAmount = 0;
    double numb1;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount: ");
        if ((numb1 = input.nextDouble()) > 0) {
            getPrincipalAmount = numb1;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data Error: Loan amount must be greater than zero. You entered " + numb1);
        }
    } while (numb1 < 0);
    return getPrincipalAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to parameterise the method: `getPrincipalAmount(double numb1)`
2. `getPrincipalAmount` must be in a method scope
3. `Scanner input` must be closed

**Try this**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class so7 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    getPrincipalAmount();
}
/** Get principal amount **/
public static double getPrincipalAmount() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double getPrincipalAmount = 0;
    double numb = 0;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Loan Amount: ");
        numb = input.nextDouble();
        if (numb > 0) {
            getPrincipalAmount = numb;
        } else {    
            System.out.println("Data Error: Loan amount must be greater than zero. You entered " + numb);
        }       
    } while (numb < 0);
    input.close();
    return getPrincipalAmount;
}
}
```